# How can write a program in scheme to find factors of a list of integer? how can extend it into arbitrarily large input?

Tags: list, integer, scheme, factors, cdr

This is the code for single integer, how can it extend to arbitrarily large input by passing list as a parameter?

```
(define (factors n)
  (define (*factors d)
    (cond ((> d n) (list))
          ((= (modulo n d) 0) (cons d (*factors (+ d 1))))
          (else (*factors (+ d 1)))))
  (*factors 1))
            
(display (factors 1111111))
(newline)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*...how can it extend to arbitrarily large input by passing list as a parameter?*"

The process described by the posted `*factors` procedure is not iterative, i.e., not tail-recursive, and it will grow stack space for large inputs. I take it that OP is interested in finding a tail-recursive version of this code to improve the space efficiency.

You can convert this to an iterative process by adding an accumulator to the helper procedure. This allows results to be stored in the accumulator and passed through recursive calls without the need for any further operations when those calls return, i.e., tail recursion.

```
(define (factors-iter n)
  (define (iter d result)
    (cond ((> d n) (reverse result))
          ((zero? (modulo n d))
           (iter (+ d 1) (cons d result)))
          (else
           (iter (+ d 1) result))))
  (iter 1 '()))
```

Here are the results of tracing the execution of these procedures:

```
> (factors-trace 8)
|(%factors 1 8)
| (%factors 2 8)
| |(%factors 3 8)
| |(%factors 4 8)
| | (%factors 5 8)
| | (%factors 6 8)
| | (%factors 7 8)
| | (%factors 8 8)
| | |(%factors 9 8)
| | |()
| | (8)
| |(4 8)
| (2 4 8)
|(1 2 4 8)
(1 2 4 8)

> (factors-iter-trace 8)
|(iter 1 8 ())
|(iter 2 8 (1))
|(iter 3 8 (2 1))
|(iter 4 8 (2 1))
|(iter 5 8 (4 2 1))
|(iter 6 8 (4 2 1))
|(iter 7 8 (4 2 1))
|(iter 8 8 (4 2 1))
|(iter 9 8 (8 4 2 1))
|(1 2 4 8)
(1 2 4 8)
```

Here `factors-trace` and `factors-iter-trace` are slightly modified versions of the `factors` and `factors-iter` definitions, allowing for a trace. You can see that the `%factors` process grows in stack size as the computation progresses, but `iter` maintains a constant stack size.

As others have already answered, the easiest way to use `factors-iter` with a list of inputs is to use `map`:

```
> (map factors-iter '(4 42 314 2998))
((1 2 4) (1 2 3 6 7 14 21 42) (1 2 157 314) (1 2 1499 2998))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a procedure that does something for one value, you can use `map` to do it for all elements of a list.

```
(map factors '(50 256 1911))
; ==> ((1 2 5 10 25 50)
;      (1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256)
;      (1 3 7 13 21 39 49 91 147 273 637 1911))
```

Comment: I need the code for arbitrarily large input, by passing list as parameter

Comment: @safump The list `'(50 256 11911)` don't need to have just 3 elements. It can be **arbitrarily large**. You can wrap it in a procedure so that you have a procedure that takes a list as argument. I'll leave that to you.